# Meaning of the word "margin" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/PudZNM276CY). It is at 15 minute and 25 second.

> Most animals live more the **margin** than most modern humans do.

Comment: I can't listen to it right now, but I'm guessing that's misheard/mistranscribed.

Comment: I would like you to listen to it when you can please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "At the margin"  (you have missed the preposition.)

Margin means "edge", in this context it metaphorically means "on the edge of survival", or "close to running out of food and other resources"

Comment: Even though I know that it is "at" there that I missed, it still cannot catch it watching the piece.  It is so frustrating. How did you catch?

Comment: A combination of a native ear and native grammatical knowledge. In other words about 150000 hours of practice.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope, the "at" in that phrase is unstressed and so the vowel that would be pronounced [æ] (that's the vowel in *cat*, *bat*, *hat*) is reduced to [ɪ̈] - the schwi - which is the second vowel in message [ˈmɛsɪ̈dʒ], climate [ˈklaɪmɪ̈t], orange [ˈɔɹɪ̈ndʒ]. She pronounces this sound quickly and softly, so that it's hard to hear anything but the [t]. To make it even worse, the [t] in *at* is glottalized (it turns into a glottal stop) because it's followed by another consonant (the *th* of "the"). Alternatively, the [t] may be an unreleased stop.  Either way, it's not a proper [t].